# Nested SQL query in PHP while-loop causes Memory Leak - What are some other solutions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, memory-leaks, sql-update

**Explanation:** I'm attempting to transfer pricing on items from one table to another by comparing code to partnumber and updating the row. The temporary table contains:

```
code        price
M1          1.23
M2          4.56
M3          7.89
```

And the second table contains:

```
partnumber  price
M2          0.00
M3          0.00
M1          0.00
```

**The issue** is that I haphazardly nested a mysql_query inside of a while loop, so I was getting a memory leak. I have around 70,000 rows of data and it bombed out at around row 160. T_T How should I go about bringing the data from the temporary table temp_yahooprices to combined_stock? Keep in mind that the server only runs PHP4 so I cannot write prepared PDO statements. The pertinent code is pasted below (and the SQL query is commented out):

```
//Import Price Data
echo 'Attempting to write Yahoo pricing data...
      <div style="margin:20px; border:1px solid #C0C0C0; overflow:scroll; height:200px; width:50%;">';
$query = "CREATE TABLE temp_yahooprices
          AS (SELECT DISTINCT
          Code AS code, 
          `Sale-price` AS price
          FROM nteproject.ynmdataz
          ORDER BY Code);";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('ERROR: Could not create temporary Yahoo pricing table. ' . mysql_error() . '<br>');
$query = "SELECT * FROM temp_yahooprices";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $price = $row['price'];
    $code = $row['code'];
    echo '<b>' . $code . '</b> = ' . $price . '<br>';
    //mysql_query("UPDATE combined_stock SET price=$price WHERE partnumber='$code'") or die("There was a problem updating pricing columns: " . mysql_error());
}
echo '</div> Pricing column was successfully created.<br><br>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all very nicely with a single SQL statement:

```
UPDATE combined_stock dest LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT price, code FROM temp_yahooprices
) src ON dest.partnumber = src.code
SET dest.price = src.price
```

This creates a temporary table called `src` based on the data from temp_yahooprices. Then it goes through your target table (combined_stock) and updates all elements where the target `partnumber` equals the source `code` and updates its price.

Comment: Thank you so much @ntaso I was attacking this problem purely from PHP when I should have been looking for an SQL solution!

Comment: Ha, glad I could help. I know exactly what you mean, because not long ago, I tried to solve too many things in PHP as well, when a good SQL command is often faster and way more elegant :)

Comment: Quick question - I performed this statement before putting it into the script, and it is certainly taking a long time to the point of giving me a 502 error on the page even though it's still running in Processes. I killed it about 30 minutes in. The tables are certainly being populated as they should, but how long do you think it would take to run through the entire data set?

Comment: Hmm, weird. 70,000 rows? That should probably take only a few seconds. Are `code` and `partnumber` unique? Do they have an index?

Comment: Partnumber uses a numeric auto-increment in ID column. The temp table is not indexed

Comment: Auto-increment is not an index itself. Try to add an index over `partnumber` and `code` in the tables. Since you JOIN these fields, an index should speed up things A LOT.

Comment: Perfect. Btw. I think I didn't state that properly above: AUTO_INCREMENT usually comes with a primary key, but its just a property. As a general hint: If you use JOIN or WHERE, it's usually good to have an index over the fields you want to JOIN/SELECT. You can make multiple indexes. They don't have much of a downside besides costing a few megabytes of storage. The speed benefits can be tremendous however. Index != Primary Key != Unique :)